# DoCmd.SendObject fails when IIS Admin Tools is installed

Tags: iis, ms-access, vba

I have an application that is written in VBA inside of Microsoft Access 2003. We have a form that allows the users to send an automated email message to the development team that uses the following code:

```
DoCmd.SendObject acSendNoObject, , , _
    "email@address.com", "", "", _
    "Helpdesk Submission", msg, False, ""
```

This code was working perfectly for all of our users until we gave the application to one of the systems administrators who had IIS Admin Tools installed on his computer. The application simply refused to send a message from the user and would fail silently.

It took us a while to figure out that the problem was IIS Admin Tools, but once we did, Internet Searches turned up nothing of value. This is basically a shot in the dark, hoping someone has an idea of a solution.

Comment: Now a solution, but just curious. Does uninstalling IIS tools restore the functionality or does it stay broke?

Comment: This should not be tagged VB6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While SendObject is an awfully easy way to send email, it's not very flexible (you can't attach a document, for instance). [Tony Toews's Email FAQ](http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/email.htm) has lots of options for sending email from Access.

Answer (score 1):

Does IIS Admin Tools have it's own mail server on it that might be conflicting.

Have you confirmed that it is IIS Admin Tools by removing it?

What about IIS?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a solution, but possibly a work around. If Outlook is installed on each users computer, you could add a reference to the outlook library and use the outlook.application object to send mail. There's a function someone has developed [here](http://www.peterssoftware.com/c_som.txt) to do just that.

Comment: If you're going to use Outlook, don't add a reference -- use late binding.